# Applescript : Text delimiter class issue

Tags: javascript, text, safari, applescript, delimiter

Hithere,

I'm grabbing text from safari using AppleScript,
I use my script for month now, but since a few day I have some difficulty with one variable with give me this result :

> 5class="name">3class="name">0class="name">6

Instead of

> 5306

Here is the script

```
set PhoneFormat to missing value
to getInputByClass(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return input
end getInputByClass
getInputByClass("field phone", 0)
set theText to Unicode text
set theSource to getInputByClass("field phone", 0) as string
property leftEdge4545 : "tel:"
property rightEdge4545 : "\">"
set saveTID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to leftEdge4545
set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
set text item delimiters to rightEdge4545
set PhoneFormat to text item 1 of classValue
set text item delimiters to saveTID
PhoneFormat

set the_phone_number to PhoneFormat
set the_last_three to characters -4 thru -1 of the_phone_number as string
```

Comment: What is the url of the page you are running it on?

Comment: it's actually and internal database